# How to convert variations of time in to minutes in R

Tags: r

I have following dataset, which H means Hour and M means minutes.

```
PT8H10M
PT20M
```

I want to convert them to minutes, and the result will be

```
490
20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
dat <- c("PT8H10M", "PT20M")

dat <- gsub("^PT|M$","", dat )

sapply( strsplit(dat, "H"), function(x)
  ifelse( length(x)==2, as.numeric(x[1])*60+as.numeric(x[2]), x ) )

[1] "490" "20"
```